# What does Rhino Mocks mean by "requires a return value or an exception to throw"?

Tags: c#, wcf, rhino-mocks

When mocking a call to a WCF Service, I get the following error:

> Method 'ICustomerEntities.GetCustomerFromPhoneNumber("01234123123");' requires a return value or an exception to throw.

I've googled this and searched on here - all I can find is I need to re-order various calls etc, but that doesn't seem to make sense in my situation? Perhaps someone could point out to me that it actually *does*?

My test setup looks like this

```
_entities = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<ICustomerEntities>();
```

And the test method fails on the third line, setting `result2`

```
_entities.Expect(ip => ip.GetCustomerFromPhoneNumber("01234123123"));
var test = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ICustomerEntities>(_factory);
var result2 = _entities.GetCustomerFromPhoneNumber("01234123123");
var result = test.GetAllCustomersWithAGivenPhoneNumber("01234123123");
Assert.AreEqual(result,result2);
```

The original call is attempting to mock this (its in a method called `GetAllCustomersWithAGivenPhoneNumber`):

```
using (var entities = _factory.CreateEntities())
{
    var customer = entities.GetCustomerFromPhoneNumber(telephoneNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remember a mocked object is just that, a mock. There is no implementation at all, so if the mock needs to return a value from a function, it has no way of knowing what to return unless you tell it.

I assume your GetCustomerFromPhoneNumber() returns a Customer object or id, so you need to tell Rhino what to return:

I've never used Rhino, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction even if the syntax isn't quite right.

```
var test = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ICustomerEntities>(_factory);
test.Stub(ent => ent.GetCustomerFromPhoneNumber("01234123123")).Return(new Customer());
```

Comment: Same issue for me...forgot the Return(). Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your _entities object is Mock, so it doesn't have the implementation. You have to specify it's bahaviour and returned value. To stub returned value You have to do the following:

```
_entities.Stub(x => x.GetCustomerFromPhoneNumber(Arg<string>.Is.Anything)).Returns(*here specify what do You want to return*);
```

For me, doing tests this way don't make sence, but it's another case.